# Passing variables in awk

Tags: bash, awk, printing

```
number=3
var="mango pineapple watermelon"
var1=("echo $var | awk '{print $number}'")
echo $var1
```

The above bash script doesnt take the value of the number as 3. I need to use a variable value after print statement in the above code. I am getting the variable number as a counter value in a for loop.How can i achieve this?

Comment: The pipeline of `echo $var |` seems completely unrelated to `number`. Enough so -- I have no idea what you are looking for here.

Comment: wrt `I am getting the variable number as a counter value in a for loop` - then your surrounding script is probably wrong. See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you have:

```
$ n=3
```

The typical way to pass that shell variable to awk would be:

```
$ awk -v n="$n" 'BEGIN {print n}'
3
```

If you want to capture that output to a new variable:

```
$ n2=$(awk -v n="$n" 'BEGIN {print n}')
$ echo "$n2"
3
```

When you roll in the pipeline input to awk, it becomes unclear what you are expecting...

---

If you are trying to select the `n`th word of a line input:

```
$ var="mango pineapple watermelon"
$ echo "$var" | awk -v n="$n" '{print $n}'
watermelon
```

And if you are trying to put that into `var2`:

```
$ var2=$(echo "$var" | awk -v n="$n" '{print $n}')
$ echo "$var2"
watermelon
```

Comment: I think they are trying to get field 3 (watermelon).

Comment: Thanks a lot for a detailed answer this really helped

Answer (score 1):

seems useless but this should work...

```
$ number=3
$ var="mango pineapple watermelon"
$ var1=$(echo "$var" | awk -v field="$number" '{print $field}')
$ echo "$var1"
```

you should get "watermelon" as var1 value.